# Can I host JScript pages using Apache Tomcat application Server?

Tags: tomcat, jscript

I have source code to **"Cube"** (which is an open-source system for visualizing time series data). The source code is in JScript.

I was wondering if I could host it on a machine which has Apache Tomcat server running on it.

Cube web page : http://square.github.com/cube/
Source code : https://github.com/square/cube

-Parag

Comment: no, but you can run it on IIS. "Classic ASP" runs on IIS.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that it is server-side JScript written in node.js. This is a platform built on top of Chrome's javascript runtime. In this case, the answer is "no", you can't run it on a tomcat server. You need to install node.js on your machine.